# How do I style this div and link within a <li> tag?

Tags: css

```
<li> <div class="test"><a href="example">Dummy</a> </div></li>
```

I have the li element styled so it has a certain height and fills the entire width of the screen. The problem is the div within in assumes the same vertical height as the li>. I try adding pad or margin and it creates a gap between the div and the li but at th expense of increasing the height of the li element, if that makes sense.

1. How do I make the div smaller? vertically? It has a background colour which is how I can see the space it is occupying.
2. Secondly, when I try to float the  anchor to the right within the div it does not work?
3. And finally, I want to have an img tag inside the div but when I put it inside, it works but then the anchor link appears below it.

I know it seems like I know nothing but these things don't seem to be in my book. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might want to change your div's closing tag, you are currently closing it after defining that class="test". It should be <div class="test"> as opposed to <div class="test" />

Comment: It would help if you'd show the CSS that you currently have.

Comment: how big is the image in relation to the text, is it like a bullet? you don't need the div  at all, the li can accomplish the styling is there a certain reason you have a div inside a li? try pasting your code in jsfiddle for us to see.

Comment: Show us what you have so far using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Alien: totally untrue. Example: `div{height:0;}`

Comment: @Nightfirecat touche~ For the life of me I can't remember why I developed that notion, but a jsfiddle just confirmed I was on crack, yay!

Comment: @Alien: No problem, we all make those kinds of silly mistakes every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

It should work - you just have one minor syntax error, change the following :

```
<div class="test" />
```

to

```
<div class="test">
```

The way you currently have it, that div isn't encapsulating anything. (If you post your CSS class `.test` I am sure myself or someone will gladly make you a working example.)

**Example:**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yqGtL/) (Going without any type of idea what you might be looking for)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo not evident in the source. I have corrected it.

Comment: Sorry about that - it was the first thing that I had noticed. What does the test class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS would be very helpful with this one.

One thing I can tell you is that the mystery heights are probably due to the Box Model - this is pretty much 90% of CSS and layout. The box model dictates that the true width or height of something is based on Margin + Border + Padding + Content. So, if you have an element that has CSS that looks like this:

```
div{margin:5px; border-width:1px; padding:5px; width:100px; height:100px;}
```

It's actual height and width are 122px... 5px (left margin) + 1px (left border) + 5px (left padding) + 100px (content) + 5px (right padding) + 1px (right border) + 5px (right margin)

I know this does not answer your question exactly, but hopefully it will help you understand what is happening better. So look at your CSS again and see where that extra height/width is coming from.

You can learn more about the box model: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

**there's also collapsing margins which are a little more complicated to explain, but you can find them [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)